# Graphical representation of vectors in 4 dimensional space

Tags: programming

I want to draw the 4-dimensional vectors.
The vectors' restrictions are:

- all elements are more than 0.
- all vectors' sum of the all elements is the same.

If 3-dim, we can draw them in an 2-dim equilateral triangle like this.

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEBlI.png)

It means that we can reduce the dimension by using this kind of figure, so
if 4-dim vectors, we can represent them by a regular tetrahedron.

I'm looking for a software or program library for drawing 4-dim vectors in such a regular tetrahedron.

I'm sorry if this question is not relevant to this forum.

Comment: Are the coordinates all non-negative integers?

Comment: Yes! All points in a grid are positive integers or 0.

Comment: I wouldn't use a tetrahedron then, I would instead make a pie chart or some percentage based chart.

Answer (score 1):

Legit 3D plots are most of the time are confusing when people cant' interact with them, because the depth is harder to perceive on a flat image.

However, if you still want to follow that path, you can normalize your vector, so the sum of the elements is $1$ and use baricentric coordinates in tetrahedron:
$$
u_i=\frac{v_i}{\sum_{j=1}^4 v_j},\qquad \vec U=\sum_{i=1}^4\vec P_iu_i,
$$
where $\vec P_i$ is coordinates of $i$-th tetrahedron vertex.

It can be done in any software sophisticated enough. For example, in Wolfram Mathematica:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. What vectors did you draw in your figure above? Could you show me the case where (3, 2, 2, 1), (2, 3, 2, 1), (2, 2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 3, 0)?

Comment: See https://i.imgur.com/KLXsMiD.png

Comment: Do you know the free software or programming language to implement this, e.g., python?

Comment: python can do this too

Comment: Thank you very much!